# Perform action on Command-Enter with NSTextView with Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstextview, appkit

An `NSTextField` can connect to an `IBAction` and will call it when the user hits the enter key.

How can I perform an action with an `NSTextView` when the user presses Command-Enter (Or Option-Enter, etc)?

Reading the documentation leads me to think it's something to do with `doCommandBySelector:` but I can't find any examples.

Comment: What kind of action? Would it make sense to just have a button or menu item whose key equivalent is ⌘↩?

Comment: @jtbandes, that's solved my problem but hasn't really answered my original question, doesn't seem like it should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can override keyDown event and check if return key code == 36 (return key) or and  key code == 76 (enter key) and modifierFlags = CommandKeyMask. Try as follow:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: NSTextView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) {
            self.keyDown(with: $0)
            return $0
        }
    }
    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.keyDown(with: event)
        if event.keyCode == 36 && event.modifierFlags.intersection(.deviceIndependentFlagsMask) == .command {
            print("command-return pressed")
        }
        if event.keyCode == 76 && event.modifierFlags.intersection(.deviceIndependentFlagsMask) == .command {
            print("command-enter pressed")
        }
    }
}
```